# Adding Google Analytics to CKeditor toolbar buttons

Tags: google-analytics, ckeditor

I'm trying to keep my Ckeditor 4 toolbar buttons to a minimum, but want figure out what buttons the users are using most.As such, I'm trying to add google analytics to toolbar button clicks.

Firing off a JS event to record the analytic is no problem. However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to capture the click event of the toolbar item specifically. Is there an event callback I can bind to? Thanks.

Ideally, this does not have to use the jquery ckeditor connector as I have managed to not use that yet. Although, it is ok to use Jquery itself.

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out. There appears to not be a way to do this at the **CKEDITOR** class level, however it can be done at the individual editor level.

Inside of my **instanceReady** handler, I can add **afterCommandExec** event handler.

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (e) {

    var textarea_id, editor;

    textarea_id = e.editor.name;
    editor = CKEDITOR.instances[textarea_id];

    // Attach handler for events
    editor.on('afterCommandExec', function (evt) {
        // Record Analytic of toolbar bar & keypress events

        // See http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.command-property-state for vals
        var cmd_name, cmd_prev_state, cmd_new_state;

        cmd_name = evt.data.name;
        cmd_prev_state = evt.data.command.state;
        cmd_new_state = evt.data.command.previousState;
        console.log([cmd_name, cmd_prev_state, cmd_new_state]);

        // Call analytics event next ...
    });
})
```

References:

- Event callbacks for the global CKEDITOR level: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-instanceReady
- Event callbacks for the editor instance level: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-afterCommandExec